# Initialising a pointer of pointers to null

Tags: c, pointers, null

If I have the following fucntion

```
int execute_command(char **args) { 
    if (args[0] == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    //more code...
}
```

How can I purposely call `execute_command(blank)` where `char **blank` would be (null) initialised in such a way to allow the if statement to be evaluated as true?

Comment: `char *arg = NULL; execute_command(&arg);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way of doing this is to create an array of pointers of size one, and set its content to `NULL`, like this:

```
char *args[] = { NULL };
```

Now you can pass this array to `execute_command`:

```
execute_command(args);
```

the array of pointers would "decay" to a pointer-to-pointer on function call, producing the effect that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`var[0]` is equivalent to `*(var + 0)`, which means that the first thing pointed to must be null.

Therefore it should be the address of a pointer to null (because it accepts `char**`), ie. `char* arg = NULL; execute_command(&arg);`.